# Display innertext into table in datagridview

Tags: vb.net

I need to display the innertext that I got from the source of a dynamic webpage into a table in datagridview.
I can only display all of them in a column but not rows by using this codes:

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim div As HtmlElement = WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("today")
    Dim spans As HtmlElementCollection = div.GetElementsByTagName("SPAN")

    For j As Integer = 0 To spans.Count - 1
        If spans(j).InnerText <> "" Then
            MessageBox.Show(spans(j).InnerText.ToString)

        End If
    Next


End Sub
```

How should I do to display them in row by row?

Comment: Are you looking for the [Columns.Add](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bc3sctb6%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) / [Rows.Add](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.rows%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) methods? I'm not quite sure what you mean.

Comment: No, as I will get a list of items from the span with different information, I need to classify them accordingly in a table but I am not sure how.